# Ember CLI with Pods

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-pods

I've been trying to move my Ember app across to use pods in preparation of 2.0.

I moved all the files, set the environment.js paramters and now my app shows nothing but the empty index.html. **What have I done wrong?**

I've attached screenshots of my setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

So as Kyle suggested in the comments, if I move my pod directories out of `/pods` and into the `/app`, and then don't set `podModulePrefix` it starts working.

But how do I get everything in `/pods`?

I tried setting `podModulePrefix` to `livin/app/pods`, `app/pods` and `livin/pods` and nothing seems to work. I don't think I undertsand the relationship of `modulePrefix` and `podModulePrefix` and the directory name of `app`. Do they all need to match?

My current directory is setup like this, if it helps.

`livin/
        app/
            pods/
                index/
                application/
                login/
            components/
            styles/
    public/
    config/`

Comment: Can I see you app.js file?

Comment: @Jakeii Added a screenshot of it now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As a side note, I have "usePods": true" set in .ember-cli, and I just use the "ember server" command in terminal.

Comment: hmm do you get any console errors? Do you have ember-inspector for your browser, do the routes routes, template, controllers etc. show up there?

Comment: Just added screenshots from firebug and form ember-inspector, when looking at index route. See anything unusual? It all looks normal to me. I'm using Ember-CLI 0.2.3.

Comment: What if you drop the podModulePrefix line from your environment file entirely and place your pods in your /app folder?

Comment: @KyleCoberly that worked! So it must be the wrong path setting. What is that path's structure supposed to be? It's confusing what that should be set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, remove podModulePrefix from your environment file and throw your pods in the root of the app folder.

I've never been able to get podModulePrefix to work, and I believe the [momentum is against putting your pods in a separate folder](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3424) anyway. Since pods are destined to be the default folder structure in the future, having your pods in the root of your app makes more sense.

Comment: Hey Kyle, I think you might be right. It does seem like 'podModulePrefix' is broken. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Given the file structure in your screenshot, your pod prefix should be 'pods', not 'livin/pods'

Comment: Tried this, still just a blank page.

Comment: One thing you can do is move the files over one at a time. You can migrate to the pod structure gradually. I think moving all the files over at once makes it difficult to trace what might have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `0.2.5` of ember-cli that might be why. `podModulePrefix` was prematurely removed in that version.
Try updating to update to `0.2.6` and see if this still occurs.